# Hybrid app with find element using content-desc is not working in flipkart app

Tags: appium

I am trying to find element for a Flipkart address form in Android using Appium. While recording with Appium inspector it returns null for the XPath in the recorded script. So I tried the following XPath:

```
Webelement name = driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[@content-desc='Enter Full Name']");
name.sendkeys("test");
```

It's showing "element not located".

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the @class in your path. Try this:

```
Webelement name = driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@class='android.widget.EditText'and @name='Enter Full Name']");
name.sendkeys("test");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But still facing the same issue.             Webelement name = driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@class='android.widget.EditText'[@content-desc='Enter Full Name']]");
name.sendkeys("test");

Comment: I tried this edited one with mentioning name also. but its not working